# How to normalise JSON data into seperate dataframe as rows and column in python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, jsonparser, json-normalize

I normalised one big nested JSON file but still getting JSON data in column refer to below example. My JSON data is as follows.

```
    data = 
    [{
  "task" : "jump",
  "taskid" : "task-001",
  "task-req" : [ {
    "taskid" : "task-001",
    "requestID" : "task-001-r1",
    }, {
    "taskid" : "task-001",
    "requestID" : "task-001-r2",
    }, {
    "taskid" : "task-001",
    "requestID" : "task-001-r3",
    } ],
  "task-desc" : {
    "task-001-r1" : [{
      "taskid" : "task-001",
      "task" : "jump",
      "details" : "long jump",
    },
    "task-001-r2" : {
      "taskid" : "task-001",
      "task" : "jump",
      "details" : "short jump",
    },
    "task-001-r3" : {
      "taskid" : "task-001",
      "task" : "jump",
      "details" : "high jump",
    }]
  }
    }]
```

I want output like below:

```
task    taskid    requistID     details
jump    task-001  task-001-r1   long jump
jump    task-001  task-001-r2   short jump
jump    task-001  task-001-r3   high jump
```

I tried using `json.normalise()` but it does not convert into the format I need. It just adding a topmost column and puts JSON data as the value in the respective row.
I am getting output as below using json.normalise()

```
task    taskid    task-req                                                  task-desc
jump    task-001  [{"taskid" : "task-002","requestID" : "task-002-r1"}  {"task-001-r1" : [{"taskid" : "task-001","task" : "jump","details" : "long jump"}]
```

do I have any way to do this?

Comment: the json data declaration does not seem to be valid. Does it run okay for you?

Comment: @MEdwin, I edited the JSON data make it smaller for more easy to understand

Comment: i think the problem is still there. But I have a feeling that the json structure is not properly formatted. You many need to work on this part. How are you getting the data?

Comment: you may have to write own code with `for`-loop to convert it.

Comment: @MEdwin, it is an already created JSON file that I need to parse I believe it is normal Nested JSON, don't know whats wrong with it :(

Comment: as for me main problem can be that it is not normal nested JSON. `task-req` doesn't have nested `desc` but it has separated item `"task-desc"`.  So it can't do it using only `json_normalize`. It needs extra code to convert this table to expected format - but I think it can be simpler if you use only `for`-loops for this (without `json_normalize`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me main problem can be that it is not normal nested JSON. `task-req` doesn't have nested `desc` but it has separated item `task-desc`. So it can't do it using only `json_normalize`. It may needs extra code to convert dataframe to expected format.

But I think it can be much simpler if you use only `for`-loops (without `json_normalize`) to create normal `list` and later convert it to `dataframe`

Your example data is incorrect. It seems you forgot some `[ ]` in `"task-desc"` so I added it. If you have different data then you should show them correctly in question.

```
data = [
{
  "task" : "jump",
  "taskid" : "task-001",
  "task-req" : [
    {
      "taskid" : "task-001",
      "requestID" : "task-001-r1",
    },
    {
      "taskid" : "task-001",
      "requestID" : "task-001-r2",
    },
    {
      "taskid" : "task-001",
      "requestID" : "task-001-r3",
    }
  ],
  "task-desc" :
  {
    "task-001-r1" : [
      {
        "taskid" : "task-001",
        "task" : "jump",
        "details" : "long jump",
      },
    ],
    "task-001-r2" : [
      {
        "taskid" : "task-001",
        "task" : "jump",
        "details" : "short jump",
      },
    ],
    "task-001-r3" : [
      {
        "taskid" : "task-001",
        "task" : "jump",
        "details" : "high jump",
      }
    ]
  }
}
]

# --- 

print('--- rows ---')

rows = []

for item in data:
    task_name = item['task']
    task_id   = item['taskid'] 

    for req in item['task-req']:
        req_id = req['requestID']

        for req_desc in item['task-desc'][req_id]: 
            details = req_desc['details']
            rows.append( [name, task_id, req_id, details] )

            print(f'{name} | {task_id} | {req_id} | {details}')
  
# ---

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['task', 'taskid', 'requistID', 'details'])

print('--- dataframe ---')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- rows ---
jump | task-001 | task-001-r1 | long jump
jump | task-001 | task-001-r2 | short jump
jump | task-001 | task-001-r3 | high jump
--- dataframe ---
   task    taskid    requistID     details
0  jump  task-001  task-001-r1   long jump
1  jump  task-001  task-001-r2  short jump
2  jump  task-001  task-001-r3   high jump
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you said about the `for` loop it clicked in my head. the data I have is wrong I guess but thank you this solution works for me